# How can I evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^4-3x^2+1}}$?

Tags: elliptic-integrals

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14051/zeros-of-the-weierstrass-pe-function/436707#436707), I reached an integral in the form

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax^4+bx^2+c}}\tag{1}$$
where $b=-3$, $c=1$. I am stack here.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20dx%2Fsqrt%28kx%5E4-3x%5E2%2B1%29) did the indefinite integral. But, I couldn't get the result for the definite integral.

Thanks for any hint, answer or reference suggestion for solving integrals in the form $(1)$.

Comment: Try factoring into $(t^2-p)(t^2-q)$ and maybe using [this formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseJacobiSN/02/0002/)

Comment: What are the restrictions on the value of $a$? Does it have some minimum value?

Comment: For general values of $a$ the integral is going to require elliptic functions or equivalent. Is that what you intended? The integrand simplifies for $a = \frac{9}{4}$, but the integral in that case diverges.

Comment: Well, looking at the link, $a = 2 + g_3/(4e_3^3)$. If we can assume $g_3/e_3^3 > 1$, then the denominator is always positive and we don't have to worry about cases with zeroes. Is this assumption valid?

Comment: Maple evaluates it in terms of elliptic integrals $F$ and $K$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog You may put your own restrictions in answer.

Answer (score 2):

[**Using**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseJacobiSN/20/01/01/0002/) the integral definition of the inverse Jacobi sn function,

$$\frac d{dz}\text{sn}^{-1}(z,m)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1-mz^2}}$$

we get:

$$\frac d{dz}\text{sn}^{-1}(a z,m)=\frac a{\sqrt{1-a^2z^2}\sqrt{1-ma^2z^2}}=\frac1{a\sqrt m\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-z^2}\sqrt{\frac1{a^2m}-z^2}}= -\frac 1{a\sqrt m\sqrt{z^2-\frac1{a^2}}\sqrt{z^2-\frac1{m a^2}}} $$

Therefore:

$$\frac1{\sqrt m}\frac d{dz}\text{sn}^{-1}\left(\frac z{\sqrt a},\frac 1m\right)=-\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt{z^2-a}\sqrt{z^2-am}}$$

and finally,

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-a)(x^2-b)}}=-\frac{\text{sn}^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt a},\frac ab\right)}{\sqrt a}= -\frac{\text{sn}^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt b},\frac ba\right)}{\sqrt b} $$

[Shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-Nintegrate%5B1%2F%28sqrt%28t%5E2-e%29sqrt%28t%5E2-pi%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D-inversejacobisn%281%2Fsqrt%28e%29%2Ce%2Fpi%29%2Fsqrt%28pi%29). Also, using [inverse Jacobi NS $\text{ns}^{-1}(z,m)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseJacobiNS/27/02/11/), and $z\in\Bbb R,m<1$ simplifies to:

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2-a)(x^2-b)}}= -\frac{\text{ns}^{-1}\left(\sqrt a,\frac ab\right)}{\sqrt a}=  -\frac{\text{ns}^{-1}\left(\sqrt b,\frac ba\right)}{\sqrt b} $$

Using [special case formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseJacobiNS/03/01/02/), one finds [Elliptic K](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticK.html):

$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}\sqrt{t^2-a}}=-\text K\left(\frac 1a\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Wolfram Alpha does not know anything about $a$.

Without any assumptions, the result write

$$-i \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{9-4 a}-3}{2 a}}\times $$ $$F\left(i \sinh ^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{2a}{\sqrt{9-4
   a}-3}}\right)|\frac{(9-2 a)-3 \sqrt{9-4 a}}{2 a}\right)$$ which will simplify depending on the value of $a$.

It is a real  $\forall a > \frac 94$